# How to use seaborn.clustermap with large (20 000 entries) data sets?

Tags: python, seaborn, cluster-analysis

I'm working a lot with [`sns.clustermap`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.clustermap.html#seaborn-clustermap) and I'm quite enjoying it as an easy tool to get an overview over a large amount of data (time series data in my case, a few hundred entries mostly).

So I figured I'll enjoy it with some larger data too, but well, not so much...

I don't mind that it takes about 6 hours to calculate on my machine, but not getting any output for those 6 hours is rather annoying.

[image: empty clustermap]

I does show the dendrogram, but the field that should contain the matrix just remains empty. Now, assuming that seaborn doesn't have inbuilt routines that deal with interpolating between pixels, this kinda makes sense. Assuming a 1 px height of a row, the matrix alone should be 20 000 pixels high with a 20 000 entries dataset. But if I increase my `figsize` to say `figsize=(400,400)` it takes a whole day and then crashes because it's out of memory and/or because my figure is too big (apparently, there's hard limit to how big a png file can be).

**Is there any way to produce a clustermap with such large data sets?**

When I run it with a *small* image size, I can produce the shown, empty picture, e.g.:

```
correlations = data.corr()
clusterplot = sns.clustermap(correlations, center=0
                            linewidths=0.4, figsize=(150, 150))
clusterplot.savefig('Cluster.png', facecolor='white', transparent=False)
```

With `data` being a pandas Dataframe with `df.shape` = `(800, 20000)`.

Since it takes quite some time and doesn't produce an error, I assume `clusterplot` contains, well, the clusterplot, but how can I get to it? Assuming there is a way, can I also calculate the clustermap without any output? I.e. something like `clusterplot = sns.clustermap(correlations, center=0, showmap=False)` to save some time?

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] of the dataset? Have you tried to set the `linewidths` to 0?

Comment: It's rather hard to imagine what you are expecting. With a clustermap, you typically show the relation between features.  Often, the features are represented as the columns of a dataframe, and a correlation matrix calculates how each column relates to each other column. There can be millions of rows.

Comment: If you have something like 100 features, there won't be much space to print the name of feature, making it hard to make sense of the dendrogram.  If there the cells are smaller than a pixel, you will only see the (white) borders between the cells.   Could you add an image of how your smaller clusterplot looks like?

Comment: I've skipped the full MWE, since actually reproducing it would lock up the reproducers machine for hours, but I edited in a bit more info. Maybe it is the `linewidth`, but that will take a few hours to find out.

Answer (score 2):

I think your white is due to the `linewidths=0.4`. The white background is just the lines covering your actual data.

Here is a small reproducible example:

```
N = 6
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((N, N)))
sns.clustermap(data=df, linewidths=5, figsize=(3, 3))
```

[image]

```
N = 60
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((N, N)))
sns.clustermap(data=df, linewidths=5, figsize=(3, 3))
```

[image]

Just set the width to zero: `linewidths=0`:

```
N = 60
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((N, N)))
sns.clustermap(data=df, linewidths=0, figsize=(3, 3))
```

[image]

To get the underlying data from the existing graph, use:

```
clusterplot.data
```